# RPi.GPIO pins - check state

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using the RPi.GPIO module in Python to turn on and off GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi 3.

Is there a way to identify whether an output pin is ON or OFF and put that value into a variable that I can use to decide whether the pin is ON and needs to turn OFF, or is OFF and needs to turn ON.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

from the [docs](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/)

[image: Doc Snippet]

The code below should provide the functionality you are looking for.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

channel = 11
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
# Setup your channel
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(channel, GPIO.LOW)

# To test the value of a pin use the .input method
channel_is_on = GPIO.input(channel)  # Returns 0 if OFF or 1 if ON

if channel_is_on:
    # Do something here
```

Comment: that works. For some reason I get an error when trying to accept the answer though.